# Is the interior of the closed unit ball, $B_{\infty}$, in $(C([0,1]),||\cdot ||_{1})$ the empty set?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball in $C([0,1])$ (the space of continuous functions) with the norm $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$.

I want to prove that $B$ has empty interior in $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot \|_{1})$, where $\|\cdot \|_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|dx$.

My fist attempt is as follows:

Let $f\in B$. Then, take the sequence $g_{n}(x)=f(x)+10\exp(-nx)$. It happens that $g_{n}\to f$ in $L^{1}$ and $g_{n}\notin B$. Right?

Am I missing something? What kind of sequences should I take?

Thank you.

Comment: "Closed unit ball" means $\{x: \|x\|\leq 1\}.$ What you are asking about is $\{x:\|x\|=1\}.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the interior is empty. If f is any point is S add $nI_(0,1/n)$ to it to get functions close to it in $L^1$  norm but with large supremum norm.

Comment: The question is about the space of continuous functions, and $nI_{(0,1/n)}$ is discontinuous at $1/n.$ Adding $\exp(-nx)$ instead would do the job.

Comment: @user438991: actually let's make it $10\exp(-nx)$ to definitely take it outside $B.$ But yes that should work.